# creatures that uses sounds/vibrations as a defense mechanism

Tags: biology, fauna, zoology

is it possible for certain creatures that can use infrasound or even vibrations as a defense mechanism, like:
- causing them to get a severe headache or even weaken them
- temporarily stunning its attackers

if it's possible, what is the exact measurement (decibel/frequency) do they need?

Answer (score 4):

There are examples of sound being used as an attack, one such being [sperm whales](https://scienceline.org/2008/05/ask-locke-whale/), unfortunately we don't know much about it as it happens far down in the deep oceans. What we do know is that their range of noises is quite loud enough to burst a human's eardrums, and as such there's a minimum safe distance for approach while diving.

It's suspected that dolphins could also stun their prey with the sonar clicks, but it's still not entirely understood.

Some [mantis shrimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_shrimp) also use a shockwave to debilitate prey, but that's taking the concept of sound to the next level as they strike so fast they cause cavitation in the water which transfers the shockwave to the target. We would normally consider sound to be a continuous wave function rather than just a single peak and trough.

The thing to take note of here is the fact these examples are all marine creatures, due to the difference in the effect of pressure waves in air and water.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples of creatures using sound as attack mean. And the difference between attack and defense is just in being worried about eating versus being eaten.

Therefore it is entirely plausible that sound can be used as defense mechanism.

It's not possible to say a priori which frequencies or power level would be needed, as that would depend on the physiology of the attacker.

Comment: even causing them to get a severe headache or even weaken them